# How to change origin rotation to be at right angles to the face

Tags: mesh, uv

How to change origin rotation to be at right angles to the face.
I try to apply it to each face. And then how to make every face have uvw in project to view in vertical position.
Is any addon or script to this or do you know how to make this?
Like this one on left side.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the face in *Edit* mode and in the *Transform Orientations* panel click on the "+" button in order to create a custom orientation (called *Face* by default), and keep this orientation selected:

[image]

In the *Options* panel, enable the *Transform Affect Only Origins* option:

[image]

Go into the header menu > *Object > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation*:

[image]

Now your origin is aligned with the face, you can disable the *Transform Affect Only Origins* option:

[image]

As for the face you want to view, maybe select the face and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>?